# Contact form sends everything to spam

Tags: php, html, spam, contact-form

1. My contact form works fine but sends everything to spam when I set the recipient as Gmail account and sends nothing if I set it as my domain email client (eg info@mydomain.com). Is there something wrong in the code? What do I need to do?

   ```
   <?php $name = $_POST['name'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $message = $_POST['message'];
   $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
   $recipient = "info@mydomain.com";
   $subject = "Contact Form";
   $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
   mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
   header('Location: message-sent.html#contact'); exit();
   ?>
   ```
2. Second question. I set up the location to redirect a user to a thank-you page. How can I set it to open in a new tab instead?